# How to record voice in twilio and play it back after a specified amount of time?

Tags: twilio

In a ruby on rails application, I have added twilio functionality for recording a user's voice for 15 seconds. The recording is working fine. As it is an asynchronous call, the request parameters are not present at the time I try to playback the audio. 
Also twilio provides a callback function which sends a post/get request on successful storing of the recording on twilio.
But there is not such functionality of callback in ruby.
How to solve this problem to playback the recording as soon as it is available?

Answer (score 0):

There is `recordingStatusCallback` functionality in Twilio's Ruby library.
(https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twilio-ruby/5.2.1/Twilio%2FTwiML%2FVoiceResponse:record)

The arguments you need to pass to `.record()` are
**`recording_status_callback`** and
**`recording_status_callback_method`**

---

Try something like this:

```
response.record(
  action: 'http://foo.edu/handleRecording',
  method: 'GET',
  max_length: 20, 
  finish_on_key: '*',
  recording_status_callback: 'http://foo.edu/handleRecordingStatus',
  recording_status_callback_method: 'GET'
)
```

---

**Parameters:**
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback)